# unable to fetch the entire organizational unit list from aws organization

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

here is my code to get the organizational unit names from root to last unit
but this works only upto 3 levels
let's say, in my organization

Root/one/two/three/{AWS Account}
Root/car/bike/twowheeler/{AWS Account}

I am expecting the output from above

Root/one/two/three
Root/car/bike/twowheeler

but i am getting only below (its returning only upto 3 levels)

Root/one/two
Root/car/bike

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('organizations')
list_roots = client.list_roots()
root_id = list_roots['Roots'][0]['Id']
root_name = list_roots['Roots'][0]['Name']
oulist = client.list_organizational_units_for_parent(ParentId=root_id)
aws_acc_ou_path = {}

for ou in oulist['OrganizationalUnits']:
    ou_path = root_name
    ou_id = ou['Id']
    ou_name = ou['Name']
    ou_path = ou_path + "/" + ou_name
    org_unit_info = client.list_organizational_units_for_parent(ParentId=ou_id)

    while True:
          for oui in org_unit_info['OrganizationalUnits']:
              org_id = oui['Id']
              ou_path = ou_path + "/" + oui['Name']
          if 'NextToken' in org_unit_info:
             org_unit_info = client.list_organizational_units_for_parent(ParentId=ou_id, NextToken=org_unit_info['NextToken'])
          else:
             break
    #print (ou_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issues here.  The first is that when you want N deep, it is better to design it a recursive function.  The second item is to be aware that organization APIs have very low max (20?) and so your first call might miss some OUs.  I prefer to use paginators since it makes it cleaner to me.

I modified from some existing code and I believe this would work for you.

```
org_client = boto3.client('organizations')
account_list = util_org.accounts_with_ou_path(org_client, 'r-xxxx', '/')
print(account_list)

def accounts_with_ou_path(org_client: boto3.client, ou_id: str, path: str) -> list:
    """ Return list of accounts at this OU as well as deeper """
    ou_list = []

    # I. Get further children ous
    paginator = org_client.get_paginator('list_children')
    pages = paginator.paginate(
        ParentId=ou_id,
        ChildType='ORGANIZATIONAL_UNIT'
    )
    for page in pages:
        for child in page['Children']:
            ou_list.extend(accounts_with_ou_path(org_client, child['Id'], path+ou_id+'/'))

    # II. Get Accounts located at ou
    pages = paginator.paginate(
        ParentId=ou_id,
        ChildType='ACCOUNT'
    )
    for page in pages:
        for child in page['Children']:
            ou_list.append(path+ou_id+'/'+child['Id'])

    return ou_list
```